# Evaluate $\int \frac{2 \sin x+ \sin 2x}{1 - \cos x }\mathrm{d}x $ by substitution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{2 \sin x+ \sin 2x}{1 - \cos x }\mathrm{d}x . $$

the following to is to be solved by substitution method. I tried to substitute $1-\cos x$, but couldn't reach the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try$u = \cos x$? Note $\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x$.

Comment: @JohnMa  No i didn't. But after you said I tried but couldn't do it. If u can show how to do it,that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\int \frac{2 \sin x+ \sin 2x}{1 - \cos x }\ dx &= \int \frac{2 \sin x+ 2\sin x\cos x}{1 - \cos x }\ dx \\ &= 2\int\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}\sin x\ dx \\ &= 2\int\frac{-(1-\cos x)+2}{1-\cos x}\frac{d(1-\cos x)}{dx}\ dx \\ &= 2\int\frac{-(1-\cos x)+2}{1-\cos x}\ {d(1-\cos x)}\end{align}$$

Does that help?

Comment: The answer is 4 log(1-cos x) + 2 cos x + c. Can you show how that is coming????

Comment: Replacing $1-\cos x$ with $u$ everywhere in that last expression gets you $2\int \frac{-u+2}{u}\ du$.  Now see if you can evaluate it.

Comment: Yeah yeah!!. My bad. Got it . Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$I=\int \frac{2 \sin( x)+ \sin (2x)}{1 - \cos (x) }\ dx = \int \frac{2 \sin (x)+ 2\sin ( x)\cos ( x)}{1 - \cos ( x) }\ dx = 2\int\frac{1+\cos( x)}{1-\cos( x)}\sin ( x)\ dx $$

Now, change variable $y=\cos(x)$, $dy=-\sin(x)\,dx$ which makes $$I=-2\int\frac{1+y}{1-y}\,dy$$ which seems easy to solve.

Comment: Can you please show the last few step and get the answer. I am having problem to do solve the last expression of yours

Comment: @user302630 Set $u = 1 - y \implies du = - dy$ and $1 + y = 2 - u$, so your integral becomes $$2 \int \frac{2 - u}{u} du =  2 \int \frac{2}{u} - 1 du$$

Answer (score 1):

$$u=1-\cos t$$
$$\int \frac{2 \sin x+ 2\sin x \cos x}{1 - \cos x }\ dx=2\int {2-u \over u} du$$

$$=\int (\frac4u-2) du=-2u+4\log u +C$$
$$=-2(1-\cos t)+4\log (1-\cos t) +C$$
$$= 2 \cos t +4\log (1-\cos t) +C'$$